# How to access a file from network in Android?

Tags: android, text-files

How do you access a plain text file on a home network (the file is kept on a Windows 7 computer). I have found several solutions on Stackoverflow for appending a string to a text file. But what I really want to do is append string to the file in the network.

Thanks!

Comment: you need a server on your windows 7 localhost

Comment: can you please elaborate a little more. What kind of server? Is not possible to access the file using the network path?

Comment: no you cant. just use XAMPP and make php file to accept http post from android and write it in text (implement of webservice)

Answer (score 0):

If your device is rooted, you can use CifsManager(Cifs/NFS) from the Google Play Store

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ws.plattner.cifsmanager&hl=en

Comment: oh i think this site is about programming